# How to Split String with 2 Foreach Perl

Tags: perl, shell, cisco

Hello I have a perl script that connected to cisco router

the actual output if not splited like this

```
show int desc
Interface                      Status         Protocol Description
Gi1/0/0                        up             up       TRUNK ME-A-JKT-TAN 5/2/1 u/ Service VPN-IP (Support QoS)
Gi1/0/0.23                     up             up       VPNIP TIGARAKSA SATRIA BSD,TANGERANG CID 20490023 TENOSS 47086151509200818077
```

then i put my code into this script like this

```
my @output1 = split(/\s{2,}/, $output);

foreach my $output2 (@output1) {
 $output3="$output2%";
 my @output4 = split(/\s{2,}/, $output3);
  foreach my $output5 (@output4) {
   print "$output5#"
 }
}
```

why the print out like this

```
show int desc
Interface%#Status%#Protocol Description
Gi1/0/0%#up%#up%#TRUNK ME-A-JKT-TAN 5/2/1 u/ Service VPN-IP (Support QoS)
Gi1/0/0.23%#up%#up%#VPNIP TIGARAKSA SATRIA BSD,TANGERANG CID 20490023 TENOSS 47086151509200818077
```

i want print out like this

```
show int desc#Interface%Status%Protocol%Description#Gi1/0/0%up%up%TRUNK ME-A-JKT-TAN 5/2/1 u/ Service VPN-IP (Support QoS)#Gi1/0/0.23%up%up%VPNIP TIGARAKSA SATRIA BSD,TANGERANG CID 20490023 TENOSS 47086151509200818077#
```

i want a 2 space or more, splited with %, and /n are splited with #
thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps because you have not `chomp`ed your lines? Also, you're adding both `#` and `%` to each line with those nested `for` loops. Your second split statement is identical to the first, what makes you think it does anything at all?

If all you want to do is replace whitespace and newline, why not just do that?

```
$output =~ s/\n+/#/g;
$output =~ s/\s{2,}/%/g;
print $output;
```

Also, you should know that it is horrible practice to name your variables `$output2`, `$output3` ... `$output5`.

Comment: thanks sir its working like a charm, sorry i'm newbie to perl :)

Comment: You're welcome. You should know that there are better ways to parse fixed width data than `split`. Check out the documentation for `substr` and `unpack`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a challenge but try this. It places the data into an array of hashes. The output is a `Data::Dumper::Dumper`. Replace it with the format you choose.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------
use Data::Dumper;

# Make Data::Dumper pretty
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent   = 1;

# Set maximum depth for Data::Dumper, zero means unlimited
local $Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = 0;

# --------------------------------------

my @Status = ();
my @field_names = ();
my $unpack_template = '';

my $in_body = 0;  #TRUE when reading the data
while( my $line = <DATA> ){
  chomp $line;

  if( $in_body ){
    my @fields = unpack( $unpack_template, $line );

    # remove trailing spaces
    s{ \s+ \z }{}msx for @fields;

    # add a hash to the Status
    my %status = ();
    for my $i ( 0 .. $#field_names ){
      $status{ $field_names[$i] } = $fields[$i];
    }
    push @Status, \%status;

  }elsif( $line =~ m{ \A Interface \b }msx ){

    # calculate unpack template
    while( length $line ){
      $line =~ s{ \A (\w+) (\s*) }{}msx;
      my $field = $1;
      my $spaces = $2;

      $unpack_template .= 'a' . ( length( $field ) + length( $spaces ));
      push @field_names, $field;
    }

    # correct the last item to read to end of line
    $unpack_template =~ s{ \d+ \z }{*}msx;

    # now reading the body
    $in_body = 1;
  }
}

print Dumper \@Status;


__DATA__
show int desc
Interface                      Status         Protocol Description
Gi1/0/0                        up             up       TRUNK ME-A-JKT-TAN 5/2/1 u/ Service VPN-IP (Support QoS)
Gi1/0/0.23                     up             up       VPNIP TIGARAKSA SATRIA BSD,TANGERANG CID 20490023 TENOSS 47086151509200818077
```